# Inequality with 3 variables involving homogeneous second degree expressions

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers. Prove that:
$$ \frac{a^2+b^2}{a^2+ab} +\frac{b^2+c^2}{b^2+bc}  +\frac{c^2+a^2}{c^2+ca} \ge \frac{9(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{(a+b+c)^2} $$

Similar problems: Advanced Olympiad Inequalities: Algebraic and Geometric Olympiad Inequalities

I've tried for Cauchy and A-GM, not much comes out

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please how exactly you used C-S or AM-GM.

Comment: I had taken this example: $$ \frac{a^4}{a^3+2b^3} +\frac{b^4}{b^3+2c^3}  +\frac{c^4}{c^3+2a^3} \ge \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{a+b+c} $$.  quivalent to prove that

$$ \frac{a^8}{a^6+2b^6} +\frac{b^8}{b^6+2c^6}  +\frac{c^8}{c^6+2a^6} \ge \frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{a^2+b^2+c^2} $$
By C-S

$$ \frac{a^8}{a^6+2b^6} +\frac{b^8}{b^6+2c^6}  +\frac{c^8}{c^6+2a^6} \ge \frac{(a^7+b^7+c^7)^2}{(a^6+b^6+c^6)^2} $$

Comment: I used this example because I already made it latex ready, I think you can understand

Comment: Your last inequality is very easy. Even the following is true. $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^4}{a^3+2b^3}\geq\frac{a^6+b^6+c^6}{a^5+b^5+c^5}.$